# Is increasing the number of channels with 1x1 convolutions a good idea?

Tags: computer-vision, convolution

Everywhere that I have seen 1x1 convolutions being used is towards reducing the dimensionality (number of channels) of features. However, I was trying to reduce the number of parameters of my model and was considering using a pooling layer followed by 1x1 convolutions in place of a convolutional layer to increase the number of channels. Are 1x1 convolutions suitable to be used for this purpose, and if yes, is this the right way to go about it?